# How to get the client ip address in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am using a payment gateway.To which I have to pass the ip address of the client ( someone using my website) . How to get it?
I tried to use the following code when I run my project in local system

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

and i got some value. But when I checked with https://www.whatismyip.com/ I got some other value. So which is correct? How can I get the correct value?
I am using asp.net MVC. is there any change in this code if we are using mvc other than asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local IP within your network is :

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[0].ToString().Dump();
```

But you can be behind a firewall / router so/your organization must have unique IP which is measured by WhatsMyIp.com

Comment: so which code I have to use? the one you given ? my website is not for local working.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting your private/local IP address assigned by your router when you do it locally,  the website you mentioned is showing you the public/external IP address that is seen by the public.

As for correcting it, you don't need to.  When a client is connected, ASP will return the correct public/external IP.

[Private vs Public IP](http://support.slingbox.com/KB/KB-2000143)

Comment: so which code I have to use for my need? I can use the same?

Comment: If you test the code from a remote location,  have your program email you the IP it's getting. (or have it log to your server somehow)